# opening and closing plots with matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I"m running into issues when trying to interactively make plots with matplotlib.pyplot.

The general sequence of events is as follows:

1) open terminal, type ipython, copy and paste commands from my sublime text into ipython, eventually typing plt.show(). 
2) viewing my nice pretty plot be made, but with one small issue I want to fix or build upon
3) closing the window that houses the plot
4) seeing the command line return to normal again. Typing plt.close(), just to make sure the plot really closed
5) copying and pasting commands again, again ending with plt.show().

Only, the result of #5 results in no plot this time!

This seems to be a problem that repeats itself, so if anyone has any input I'd be very grateful. I noticed that when I create the plot the first time, it creates a plot window (which I can see with Command-Tab​​ Application Switcher). When I try to close this after making the plot the first time, this window never actually disappears from the Application Switcher.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just run your script directly from Sublime?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - thats precisely what I might start doing.

Comment: No problem. Also, you might want to consider installing [`SublimeREPL`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) and running IPython inside of it. Combine that with the [`Anaconda`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda) auto-complete plugin (no relation to the Anaconda Python distribution) and you've got yourself a pretty sweet Python coding setup.

Comment: run `%matplotlib` at the ipython prompt an you will be able to have both the plot and the repl command line up interactively.